# Speeding Up My Current Code Inventory Management Planning Screen

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I first want to apologize for dumping a lot of code into here, but I have been stuck on this issue for days. I was assigned to build a planning screen wherein I could pull corresponding information regarding Sales, Production, and Inventory. As a preface to all of this, this code works for me and does exactly what I need it to do. I originally posted this in Stack Overflow, but someone mentioned I should also post it here. I also want to note that the SpeedUp and SpeedDown functions are in a different module and are used to affect: Screen Updating, Events, Calculations, and the Status Bar.

The problem, however, is the amount of time it takes to run. Originally, it was taking about 5-7 minutes, but I have been able to reduce it to 1-2 minutes depending on the computer being used. I have tried changing multiple things, and can not reduce the time more. Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub FillInventoryAcross()
'This code is the formulas for the Total Inventory, Sales, and Production Data. Just addition formulas.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strFormulas(1) = "=SUM(C15,C20,C25,C30,C35,C40)"
strFormulas(2) = "=SUM(C16,C21,C26,C31,C36,C41)"
strFormulas(3) = "=SUM(C18,C23,C28,C33,C38,C43)"

.Range("C11:W11").formula = strFormulas(1)
.Range("C11:W11").FillRight
.Range("C12:W12").formula = strFormulas(2)
.Range("C12:W12").FillRight
.Range("C13:W13").formula = strFormulas(3)
.Range("C13:W13").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub FillInventoryPerLocation()
'This code will fill in the inventory per location. It will add up all of the sales, movement and production per plant along with the prior days inventory.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 12) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L95"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0))+SUM(C16:C19)+C46,0),0)"
strformula(2) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L90"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C21:C24),0)"
strformula(3) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L91"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C26:C29),0)"
strformula(4) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L93"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C31:C34),0)"
strformula(5) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L94"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C36:C39),0)"
strformula(6) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""A78"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C41:C44),0)"
strformula(7) = "=C15+Sum(D16:D19)+D46"
strformula(8) = "=C20+sum(D21:D24)"
strformula(9) = "=C25+sum(D26:D29)"
strformula(10) = "=C30+sum(D31:D34)"
strformula(11) = "=C35+sum(D36:D39)"
strformula(12) = "=C40+sum(D41:D44)"
.Range("C15").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C20").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C25").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C30").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C35").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C40").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("D15:W15").formula = strformula(7)
.Range("D15:W15").FillRight
.Range("D20:W20").formula = strformula(8)
.Range("D20:W20").FillRight
.Range("D25:W25").formula = strformula(9)
.Range("D25:W25").FillRight
.Range("D30:W30").formula = strformula(10)
.Range("D30:W30").FillRight
.Range("D35:W35").formula = strformula(11)
.Range("D35:W35").FillRight
.Range("D40:W40").formula = strformula(12)
.Range("D40:W40").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SumIfSales()
'This code will pull up all of the sales information for a product. Just a Sumif looking up information that matches Date/SKU. After the code is in the starting cell, it is then dragged accross for all of the other dates.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 6) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L95"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L90"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L91"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L93"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L94"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""A78"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
.Range("C16:W16").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C16:W16").FillRight
.Range("C21:W21").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C21:W21").FillRight
.Range("C26:W26").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C26:W26").FillRight
.Range("C31:W31").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C31:W31").FillRight
.Range("C36:W36").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C36:W36").FillRight
.Range("C41:W41").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("C41:W41").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SumIfMovement()
'This code works in a similar way to the prior code, but looks to match Date/SKU to find product movement.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 6) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""95"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L95""))"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""90"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L90""))"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""91"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L91""))"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""93"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L93""))"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""94"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L94""))"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""78"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""A78""))"
.Range("C17:W17").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C17:W17").FillRight
.Range("C22:W22").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C22:W22").FillRight
.Range("C27:W27").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C27:W27").FillRight
.Range("C32:W32").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C32:W32").FillRight
.Range("C37:W37").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C37:W37").FillRight
.Range("C42:W42").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("C42:W42").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SumIfProduction()
'This code yet again works like the other two codes, but for production.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 6) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P95""))"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P90""))"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P91""))"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P93""))"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P94""))"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""A78""))"
.Range("C18:W18").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C18:W18").FillRight
.Range("C23:W23").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C23:W23").FillRight
.Range("C28:W28").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C28:W28").FillRight
.Range("C33:W33").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C33:W33").FillRight
.Range("C38:W38").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C38:W38").FillRight
.Range("C43:W43").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("C43:W43").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub DailySalesHistory()
'This code works to look up the Sales History by day for a given product. Takes each starting Monday and will add a day to it accross until Sunday, then the next week starts. Does the Date/SKU thing like the other sections. It then multiplies the end value by -1 to make the sales values positive, as the user would like to see them as.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 7) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+1,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+2,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+3,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+4,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+5,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(7) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+6,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
.Range("D51").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("D51:D108").FillDown
.Range("E51").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("E51:E108").FillDown
.Range("F51").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("F51:F108").FillDown
.Range("G51").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("G51:G108").FillDown
.Range("H51").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("H51:H108").FillDown
.Range("I51").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("I51:I108").FillDown
.Range("J51").formula = strformula(7)
.Range("J51:J108").FillDown
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub WeeklySalesHistory()
'This code will take all of the valuse returned in the prior code and add them together. This will give the user the total sales of a product for a given week.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K51").formula = "=SUM(D51:J51)"
Range("K51:K108").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub TopDaysoftheWeek()
'This code will bring up the days of the week for three weeks. Starts with Sunday and ends with Saturday. First formula finds the Sunday, the other formulas just adds 1 to the day.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C8").formula = "=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("D8").formula = "=C8+1"
Range("D8:W8").FillRight
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub InventoryInfo()
'This code runs vlookups on the inputted SKU number to pull up corresponding information. If the cell is blank, it will tell the user what will come up. If there is an error, it will reflect that.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""SKU Number"",INDEX(ItemMaster!$B:$B,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Product Name"",IF(ISTEXT(INDEX(ItemMaster!$D:$D,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))),INDEX(ItemMaster!$D:$D,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0)),INDEX(ItemMaster!$C:$C,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("F6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Pieces Per Case in"",INDEX(ItemMaster!$I:$I,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0)))&"" pieces"""
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("I6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Pieces Per Case in "",(ROUND(INDEX(ItemMaster!$J:$J,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))*35.274,2)))&"" Oz"""""
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L6").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Date of Last Run"",MAX(IF(Production!$H:$H=Inventory!$M$3,Production!$N:$N)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("N6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Line of Last Run"",INDEX(Production!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Production!$H:$H,0)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("P6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Allergen Codes"",""Codes: ""&$AI$5)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("Q6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$6)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("R6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$7)"
 Worksheets("Inventory").Range("S6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$8)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("T6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$9)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("U6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$10)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("V6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$11)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("W6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$12)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("E10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Cases Per Dough"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE($M$3),CPD!$A$1:$D$381,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE($M$3),CPD!$A$1:$D$381,2,FALSE)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("J10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Lines Product Was Run On"",""Lines: ""&$AO$5)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO6),ISNA(AO6)),"""",AO6))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO7),ISNA(AO7)),"""",AO7))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("M10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO8),ISNA(AO8)),"""",AO8))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("N10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO9),ISNA(AO9)),"""",AO9))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("O10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Average Cases Sold Per Week"", SUM(K56:K67)/12)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("R10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Average Cases Sold Per Day"", $O$10/7)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("U10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Days of Inventory Remaining"",(INDEX(Inventori!$F:$F,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)))/R10)"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub HiddenFormulas()
'This code runs some of the hidden formulas used to calculate and find factors for the inventory screen. The user will not be allowed to see or interact with them.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF5").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$K:$K,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF6").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$L:$L,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF7").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$M:$M,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF8").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$N:$N,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF9").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$O:$O,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF10").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$P:$P,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF11").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$Q:$Q,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF12").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$R:$R,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI5").formula = "=IF($AF$5=""X"",""O"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI6").formula = "=IF(AF6=""X"",""A"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI7").formula = "=IF(AF7=""X"",""B"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI8").formula = "=IF(AF8=""X"",""C"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI9").formula = "=IF(AF9=""X"",""AB"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI10").formula = "=IF(AF10=""X"",""AC"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI11").formula = "=IF(AF11=""X"",""BC"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI12").formula = "=IF(AF12=""X"",""ABC"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AL5").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Production!$E:$E, SMALL(IF(Inventory!$M$3=Production!$H:$H, ROW(Production!$H:$H)-ROW($A$1)+1), ROW(1:1)))"
Range("AL5:AL554").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO5").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO4,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO6").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO5,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO7").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO6,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Invnetory").Range("AO8").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO7,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO9").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO8,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub BottomDaysoftheWeek()
'This code runs with TopDaysoftheWeek. Thile that code will pull up the date of each day, this code will convert that into the name of the day.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C9").formula = "=TEXT(C8,""ddd"")"
Range("C9:W9").FillRight
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SalesHistoryByMonth()
'This code finds the months for Sales History. It will find the month ahead of the current month all the way until a year prior.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L51").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L53").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L55").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L57").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-3)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L59").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L61").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L63").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-6)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L65").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-7)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L67").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-8)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L69").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-9)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L71").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-10)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L73").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-11)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L75").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-12)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L77").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-13)+1"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SalesHistoryWeeks()
'This code finds the weeks of sales history. The first formula takes the first date of the inventory section and adds 6 weeks to it. The following formula just decreases the week by a week until the end of the table.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B51").formula = "=(C8+42)-WEEKDAY(C8,3)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B52").formula = "=B51-7"
Range("B52:B108").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SalesHistoryMonthlyCalculations()
'This code calculates the sales history by month. It works by adding together all of the weekly sales history to the left of these formulas based on if the weeks are within the corresponding month. This formula is a little iffy, where it works on a beginning of the week basis (i.e. 5/28-6/4 counts as May, not May and June). Aside form that, works really well. May need to rework this formula.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L52").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L51,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L51,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L54").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L53,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L53,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L56").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L55,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L55,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L58").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L57,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L57,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L60").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L59,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L59,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L62").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L61,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L61,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L64").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L63,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L63,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L66").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L65,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L65,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L68").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L67,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L67,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L70").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L69,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L69,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L72").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L71,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L71,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L74").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L73,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L73,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L76").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L75,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L75,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L78").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L77,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L77,0))"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub ProductionHistoryInfo()
'This code is all of the formulas regarding Production History. Finds Cases, Doughs, and Line product was run on. Also has the yield formulas (cases/doughs).
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("Q52").FormulaArray = "=IF(OR(($O52)="""",$O52=DATE(1900,1,0)),"""",INDEX(Production!$R:$R,MATCH(CONCATENATE(Inventory!$O52,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$B:$B,0)))"
Range("Q52:Q104").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("R52").formula = "0"
Range("R52:R104").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("S52").FormulaArray = "=IF(OR(($O52)="""",$O52=DATE(1900,1,0)),"""",INDEX(Production!$E:$E,MATCH(CONCATENATE(Inventory!$O52,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$B:$B,0)))"
Range("S52:S104").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("T52").formula = "=IF(ISERR(Q52/R52),"""",Q52/R52)"
Range("T52:T104").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub ProductionHistoryDates()
'This code finds the dates that a given product was run on. Uses an array function to look up dates of production based on matching SKU numbers. Most volatile function in this section. Can only lookup/match up to 20,000 values, which could be problematic. May need some editing done based on how actual tables are set up. Goes from oldest to newest, which may also be a problem.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("O52").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(OFFSET(Production!$H$1:$H$100000,SMALL(IF(Production!$H$1:$H$100000=Inventory!$M$3,ROW(Production!$H$1:$H$100000)-ROW(INDEX(Production!$H$1:$H$100000,1,1))),ROW()-51),COLUMN()-9),"""")"
Range("O52:O104").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub BorderFixer()
'This code was created after I discovered that some of these vba formulas will break the borders I made after running. Its only purpose is to fill in those broken borders and fix them to look like how they looked before.

 With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("W10").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlThin
.ColorIndex = 2
End With

   With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("W7:W43").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
  .Weight = xlThin
  .ColorIndex = 2
   End With

   With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B108:K108").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
  .Weight = xlThin
  .ColorIndex = 2
  End With

 With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K108").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
 .Weight = xlThin
 .ColorIndex = 2
 End With
 End Sub

Sub ResetInventory()
'This code is made to run only if the user manages to unlock all of the cells on this sheet and start deleting the formulas I added. Once clicked, this code will: deactivate all of Excel's functions, run all of the prior codes related to inventory, run the border fixer to repair broken borders, and reactivate Excel's functions. While it runs fast and effectively, has a chance to break the worksheet. If so, click fix frozen cells. Will return error if the user tries to run this while sheets are protected.
 Call SpeedUp
 Call InventoryInfo
 Call TopDaysoftheWeek
 Call BottomDaysoftheWeek
 Call SumIfSales
 Call SumIfMovement
 Call SumIfProduction
 Call FillInventoryPerLocation
 Call FillInventoryAcross
 Call BorderFixer
 Call CPD
 Call SpeedDown
 End Sub

Sub ResetSalesHistory()
'This code is made to run only if the user manages to unlock all of the cells on this sheet and start deleting the formulas I added. Once clicked, this code will: deactivate all of Excel's functions, run all of the prior codes related to sales history, run the border fixer to repair broken borders, and reactivate Excel's functions. While it runs fast and effectively, has a chance to break the worksheet. If so, click fix frozen cells. Will return error if the user tries to run this while sheets are protected.
Call SpeedUp
Call SalesHistoryWeeks
Call DailySalesHistory
Call WeeklySalesHistory
Call SalesHistoryByMonth
Call SalesHistoryMonthlyCalculations
Call BorderFixer
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub ResetProductionHistory()
'This code is made to run only if the user manages to unlock all of the cells on this sheet and start deleting the formulas I added. Once clicked, this code will: deactivate all of Excel's functions, run all of the prior codes related to production history, run the border fixer to repair broken borders, and reactivate Excel's functions. While it runs fast and effectively, has a chance to break the worksheet. If so, click fix frozen cells. Will return error if the user tries to run this while sheets are protected.
Call SpeedUp
Call ProductionHistoryDates
Call ProductionHistoryInfo
Call BorderFixer
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub InventoryPrintPreview()
'This code is made to show the users a print preview of what the worksheet will look like. I already made the print areas for the three tables on this sheet. User can change margins or format.
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
Worksheets("Inventory").PrintPreview
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
End Sub
```

Comment: First off, any time you are working on the worksheet you are costing yourself performance (e.g FillRight, FormulaR1C1, etc). I would suggest learning about arrays and see if you can accomplish the task with arrays. You can easily reduce minutes to seconds with arrays. For the short term though, you need to use more With blocks. Any time you have multiple lines using the same object, just use a With block. It reduces the time a little bit, but can add up if you're repeatedly using the object. Plus, it makes the code cleaner.

Comment: Have you considered putting all the formulas into an XLTM, locking the cells with formulas and putting a password on it so people cannot (easily) overwrite the formulas? This way, the user can open the .XLTM file, have a clean workbook to work with that has all the formulas in it and simply plug in the variable info where it needs to be? Just trying to think a little outside the box - i realize this may not solve the problem _you_ need to solve.

Comment: FreeMan - I am currently saving my workbook as a xlsb file. It was recommended to me by someone to help reduce time. I can look into changing the file type, but I know the change helped.
Brandon - Someone in the Stack Overflow thread also mentioned cutting down on the Fill formulas, as most of my code was doing something like it and that was being redundant. I am currently in the process of changing the code to reflect this. I have been messing around with the Array method you mentioned and can't seem to get Arrays to work within my With Statements. I was wondering if you had any advice?

Comment: It's not clear (at least for me) which is your main formula. And also which part is so time consuming. You should parts of your code to identify the bottleneck so we could help to improve that part.

Comment: @Máté Juhász - I am a little confused by the first part of your statement. However, I can say that I am almost certain my problems are stemming from the SUMIFS statements. The problem is that the current code gets me the results I want. So while I think it is the problem, I am unsure how to fix it. Whenever I tried changing the code, it would usually run slower. So any advice to improve my work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `FillRight` -

> ```
> .Range("C16:W16").Formula = strformula(1)
> .Range("C16:W16").FillRight
> ```

You only need to assign the formula to the first cell

```
.Range("C16").Formula = strformula(1)
```

But, I don't think that's really what you want to do. You want to work with the data directly. With *something like* this

```
sumRange = Sheets(Sales).Range("I1:I200000")
firstCriteriaRange = Sheets(Sales).Range("B1:B200000")
firstCriteria = "L95"
secondCriteriaRange = Sheets(Sales).Range("D1:D200000")
secondCriteria = Sheets(Inventory).Range("C8") & Sheets(Inventory).Range("M3")
thirdCriteriaRange = Sheets(Sales).Range("AD1:AD200000")
thirdCriteria = "VN"
Dim i As Long
Dim total As Long
For i = LBound(sumRange) To UBound(sumRange)
    If firstCriteriaRange(i) = firstCriteria And secondCriteriaRange(i) = secondCriteria And thirdCriteriaRange(i) = thirdCriteria Then
        total = total + sumRange(i)
    End If
Next
```

Or make that `Total` an array as well. This isn't word for word what to use, but just an example of how it might be. As you loop, you can fill in the array and then print the array to the entire range at once. Much faster.

And you can do that with everything, instead of the formulas, unless, of course, you need the formulas to be on the sheet. Then at least construct them all in one array and print that to the range at once.